# Observable-Observer RxPy pattern with asyncio

Tags: python, tkinter, python-asyncio, rx-py

Is there any way to integrate RxPy observable and subscribe functions in a way that lets you process a list of items concurrently with asyncio and such that every time an item is processed it notifies the observer subscribed?

```
    async def process():
        list=await get_list(url)
        other_list=await asyncio.gather(*[more_process(item,windowObserver) for item in list])

        return 
    

    total_images=asyncio.ensure_future(search())
```

This is supposed to be working with a Tkinter window that acts as the observer and is the one handling the actions when notified.

Also that windows is the one handling the above code when a button is pressed.

Comment: What does this have to do with tkinter? You don't mention it in the title, body, or in the code.

Comment: @BryanOakley Totally true, I have just updated the description.